# A.C through Capacitor when A.C Voltage is just supplied

Tags: electric-circuits

Consider a simple circuit of a capacitor connected with an A.C source.
When the rate of change of Voltage is max then charges will move faster so current will be max, thus following graph is obtained:[image]

But I just can't imagine what would be the situation at just the initial moments of turning the switch on? Initially both V and I should be zero but since ∆V/∆t would be maximum so current should be maximum i.e, charge should be moving with max speed at just the initial moment (but that isn't possible because charges are at rest).
Thus, I think that the above graph is just showing some intermediate situation not the initial one. So (if my assumption is correct) what would be the graph which is plotted when when switch is just turned on?

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, I think that the above graph is just showing some intermediate
> situation not the initial one.

The graph is showing the relationship between voltage and current under steady state conditions, i.e., a long time after the switch connects the capacitor to the ac source so that transients have died out.

> So (if my assumption is correct) what would be the graph which is
> plotted when when switch is just turned on?

Since the voltage across an ideal capacitor cannot change instantaneously, there needs to be some resistance in the circuit  (not shown in your circuit) that limits the current when a switch first connects the capacitor to the voltage source. Otherwise the initial transient current would be infinite.

So if you include the initial transient period after the switch is turned on, the current will initially be a maximum equal to the voltage source divided by the resistance in the circuit. Then its magnitude will decrease exponentially until reaching steady state, as shown in the figure below (which does not include the voltage waveform),  where its magnitude will equal the voltage divided by the series impedance of the capacitance reactance plus the resistance in the circuit.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: If we consider the resistance in the circuit, then there would be delay in the voltage across capacitor from the voltage of the source. So the ∆Q/∆t graph (where Q is charge stored in capacitor) would not be inphase with the applied voltage. Thus the phase difference between the current and voltage would NOT be exactly 90°, isn't it? (Becase: current=∆Q/∆t)

Comment: @BobD The presence of oscillatory behaviour would mean that there was also inductance in the circuit with the transient frequency not necessarily equal to the frequency of the voltage source.

Comment: @Farcher not sure I follow you. The current is ac. I am not assuming any inductance.  I am only showing the transient behavior which is the ac current in an exponentially decaying envelope for a much larger time constant than your diagram.

Comment: @BobD I have run another simulation which shows the steady state response with a decaying dc transient which subtly differs from your graph.

Comment: @Farcher I didn't create the graph. Simply looked for an image of a damped sinusoid on the internet to get the idea across. I was surprised I couldn't find any images of an ac transient response for a series RC circuit. They're all dc. As I see it it would a dc response superimposed on the steady state ac wave.

Comment: @RobD I understand as to the difficultly of finding suitable graphs and that is why I performed the simulation.  The transient in your graph is oscillatory which I do not think can happen unless you have inductance in the circuit and the system is under-damped.

Comment: @Farcher The transient in the graph isn't oscillatory. The transient is in the peak current of each cycle. I don't see how it's any different than the black current waveform in your 3rd transient analysis graph except that it lasts about 10 cycles whereas yours lasts about 3 cycles due to a different value of RC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132702/discussion-between-farcher-and-bob-d).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @BobD the graphs displayed in the question are for the steady state after any transients have died away.

Dealing with zero resistance circuits sometimes leads to a situation which cannot exist and so it is best to analyse circuits as though they had resistance and then to see what the effect is if the resistance is made smaller and smaller.
With this in mind one might also note that the circuit also has inductance and this might also be included in any analysis of this type.

To illustrate this consider the following circuit shown below which I have set up using the [Spinning Numbers Circuit Sandbox Simulator](https://spinningnumbers.org/).

[image]

In series is a sinusoidal voltage source of amplitude $1\,\rm V$ and frequency $1\,\rm Hz$, a $1\Omega$ resistor and a $1\,\rm mF$ capacitor.
There are two voltage probes (red and black) and a current probe.

Running a transient response for $1\,\rm s$ (ie switching the circuit on at time equal zero and taking readings for one second gives the following response in which it looks as though the steady state is achieved instantaneously, the vertical mauve pink (current) line at the start.

[image]

However reducing the observation time to $70 \rm ms$ shows a characteristic decay curve for the transient (together with the steady state).

[image]

For such a $CR$ circuit the time constant $CR = 1 \times 10^{-3} = 1 \rm \, ms$ which is consistent with the time scale shown by the pink (current) graph.

[To run the simulation just click this link.](https://spinningnumbers.org/circuit-sandbox/index.html?value=%5B%5B%22v%22%2C%5B112%2C72%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22sin(0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0)%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A0%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22c%22%2C%5B208%2C72%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22c%22%3A%221m%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A1%7D%2C%5B%223%22%2C%221%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22r%22%2C%5B176%2C48%2C1%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22r%22%3A%221%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A2%7D%2C%5B%223%22%2C%222%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B112%2C72%2C112%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B176%2C48%2C208%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B208%2C48%2C208%2C72%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B112%2C120%2C112%2C144%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B208%2C120%2C208%2C144%5D%5D%2C%5B%22g%22%2C%5B112%2C144%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22_json_%22%3A8%7D%2C%5B%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22s%22%2C%5B208%2C48%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22black%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A9%7D%2C%5B%223%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22s%22%2C%5B112%2C48%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22red%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%2200.1%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A10%7D%2C%5B%222%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B112%2C48%2C128%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B128%2C48%2C128%2C48%5D%5D%2C%5B%22a%22%2C%5B168%2C144%2C2%5D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22magenta%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A13%7D%2C%5B%221%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B168%2C144%2C208%2C144%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B152%2C144%2C112%2C144%5D%5D%2C%5B%22view%22%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C%2250%22%2C%2210%22%2C%221G%22%2C%22%22%2C%22100%22%2C%220.06%22%2C%221000%22%5D%5D)

So as the resistance in the circuit decreases so does the period over which the transient exists.

---

With the same vales as before except that the resistance value is $1\,\rm k\Omega$ and thus a time period of $1\,\rm s$ the response of the circuit is as follows.

[image]

Note the ac with a decaying dc offset (the transient) over the first few seconds.